# Command line for copying a file named for its parent directory

Tags: shell

I am having a brain cramp here.  I'd like to be able to do something like this ...

```
$ pwd
/user/red/thing1
$ cp ../file.txt basename `pwd`.txt
```

... and have the resulting file be named `thing1.txt`. When I run the above command line I get this error, ``` cp: target ``/users/red/thing1/thing1.txt' is not a directory ```, which seems odd to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to copy basename as well which would mean multiple copies of files to a directory.

Perhaps you mean this:

```
cp ../file.txt "$(basename $(pwd)).txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cp ../file.txt $(basename $(pwd)).txt
```

Don't try that with back-quotes:

```
cp ../file.txt `basename \`pwd\``.txt
```

OK — it is doable but not as ease as with `$(...)`.

This assumes no blanks in the base name; add double quotes around the `"$(...)"` if you need to worry about blanks. Don't even think about trying that with back-quotes.